# Write to file, but interpret/remove (get rid of) terminal escape sequences

Tags: bash, terminal, escaping

I have a file (from a terminal session recording using `script`) that contains a bunch of escape sequences (ANSI colors and backspaces and so on) that the terminal interprets when this file is displayed with `cat` for example. However, if I use

```
cat myFile > newfile
```

the escape sequences are not interpreted/removed, and are written as they are to the new file. This is true not only for cat, in fact I have found it impossible to get rid of those escape sequences. I want to clean the file up and keep only the printing characters (whitespace and newlines included) so that someone on another terminal or program could view it without compatibility issues.

There are many other threads about this, so I'll specify why I am not happy with the answers in those:

1. People are suggesting to use `sed` or similar with some more or less (mostly more) complicated regular expressions to remove the escape sequences. Not supricingly, those threads are full of comments showing examples where those expressions break. Thus, unless you can prove that your regular expression completely re-implements the macOS terminal escape sequence interpretation/removal, that's not the type of solution I am interested in. There are other threads for that.
2. Copy pasting from the terminal window is of course also an option but I am already aware of that.

Somewhere on their way between cat (or echo, or printf) and appearing on the screen, these escape sequences are interpreted. Is it possible to intercept them after that point and print them to a file instead?

It is annoying that there is no straight forward/easy way to do this when it is so easy to get exactly the text I want in the file printed on screen.

Finally, code example so you can replicate:

`cat` the file:

```
[anton@rain test]$ cat session.log 
Script started on Thu Jun 14 18:06:38 2018
[anton@rain test]$ echo 'okay, now it seems to be working' 
okay, now it seems to be working
[anton@rain test]$ 
[anton@rain test]$ exit 
exit

Script done on Thu Jun 14 18:06:59 2018
```

Note: When I copy the text here from terminal, the original colours are not preserved. I have a coloured command prompt (see the escape sequences below).

File viewed using `less`:

```
Script started on Thu Jun 14 18:06:38 2018
ESC]0;anton@rain:/MD/home/anton/tests/test^GESC[?1034hESC[00;35m[anton@rain test]$ ESC[00;30m^G^Gecho 'okay, now it seems to be working'
okay, now it seems to be working
ESC]0;anton@rain:/MD/home/anton/tests/test^GESC[00;35m[anton@rain test]$ ESC[00;30mESC[K
ESC]0;anton@rain:/MD/home/anton/tests/test^GESC[00;35m[anton@rain test]$ ESC[00;30mexit
exit

Script done on Thu Jun 14 18:06:59 2018
```

Note: When I copy paste back into the terminal from this post, the file does  not work the same way as before. It might be better to run `script` yourselves to replicate.

Comment: Escape sequences are characters, too. So programs will faithfully interpret and display them. For `less`, what about `less -R` to display pretty colors?

Comment: @CalvinKim Thanks, but pretty printing in less does not solve my problem. Try redirecting to a file like `less -R fileWithEscapeSeqs > newfile` and you will see that all the escape sequences are still there in the new file. The issue is that I can easily show file contents on screen just like I want them, but getting the plain text version of that into a file seems really tricky (wo resorting to methods outside the shell).

Comment: Have you found a solution for that? I'm looking for the exact same thing

Comment: No. Or if I did, I no longer remember. It was a long time ago. Interesting to rediscover my old questions though. Even more interesting to hear others have the same issues. What I  do know is that I don't use recordings of shell sessions these days. So my "solution" was probably to not rely on them for whatever documentation I was planning to use them for. A bit of an XY problem situation

Comment: I might add that if I had found a solution for this specific problem anywhere close in time to when I asked it, it would likely be on here, since I tend to make an effort answering my own questions in such circumstances. In my head, if I've used the communitys time to ask a question, I owe the community the answer if I find it myself. So I most likely didn't find a satisfying solution in this case.